# Dell T410 Memory Upgrade - mixing sizes

Tags: memory, dell-poweredge

We have a Dell T410 server using 4x2GB RDIMMs for a total of 8GB.
I thought I would be able to replace 2 of those 2GB RDIMMs with 2x4GB RDIMMs to increase our total RAM from 8GB to 12GB.

However, I am very confused by how this works.  According to the manual:
* Channel 0 is DIMM slots A4 and A1
* Channel 1 is DIMM slot A2
* Channel 2 is DIMM slot A3
* Memory modules of different sizes can be mixed within a memory channel (for example, 2-GB and 4-GB), but all populated channels must have identical configurations. This applies to only channel 0.

How can I mix my RDIMMs in this configuration?  Is there a way to do this without having the system report a non-optimal configuration?

EDIT: Also, I'm only using the first memory bank since we're only using a single CPU right now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll want to put the 2 4GB RDIMMs in the first slot on each processor's side. They match.
Then populate the other RDIMMs appropriately.

When populating RAM, you typically want the largest in the first slots and then work your way down.

Comment: Sorry, I should add that I'm only using the first memory bank in a single CPU setup.

Comment: Same theory pretty much applies. In A4 & A1 you'll place your 4GB, populate the others with the 2GB.